# Arbitrary joins in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, join, django-orm

Let's say model `X` has a field `n` (an integer). Now I also have a model `Y` which has fields `n` and `m` (integers). Is it possible using Django ORM to select `x` (model `X`) such that there exists `y` (model `Y`) such that `x.n = y.n` and `y.m = m` for a given value of `m`?

Please don't advise me to introduce a `ForeignKey` relationship between the two models or anything like that. I'd like to know specifically if it's possible to achieve this without modifying the model. In the exact case that I'm working on, the given relationships are generic. And the opposite side of the generic relationship can be anything, so according to the docs I cannot really introduce `GenericRelation` multiple times in different models.

Comment: Is it only me or is this a serious gap in functionality? How is it possible that it's not trivial? I start to think that the fact that they keep their code in svn is a bad sign.

Comment: In the Django world, less constraining than you might think. If you want to do arbitrary joins, raw SQL (returning real model objects) is there for you. And... you know, I like git and Mercurial too, but if the biggest complain one has about an open source project is its taste in source code control tools, one has reached paradise.

Comment: @Christophe The problem with raw SQL is that you need to generate table names by hand, column names by hand. And I think it renders current transaction as dirty. I know it's possible, but if every time I need to do something just a little bit non-standard, I need to resort to writing SQL by hand, I'd rather not use ORM at all. After quite some time spent with Django ORM, I think it is seriously broken by design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i suppose this could be achieved using [`extra`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) `QuerySet` method.

(i didn't tested it)

```
X.objects.extra(where=["x.n in (select y.n from y where y.m = '%s')"], params=['m_value'])
```

Comment: Well, it does work after a few minor changes in the naming. According to what I read it also performs better than a regular JOIN. Thanks.

Comment: queryset.query.get_initial_alias() to get the alias assigned to the primary table in the query.  also SomeModel._meta.db_table has the underlying table name for any model.

Comment: While this may be what you need, the "extra" method is being deprecated, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using raw sql:

```
def my_custom_sql(m):
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Data retrieval operation - no commit required

    command = """SELECT * 
      FROM tX 
INNER JOIN tY
        ON (tX.n=tY.n AND tY.m=%s)"""

    cursor.execute(command % str(m))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    return rows
```

using the ORM, i think you can do this using `values_list` and the `in` filter:

```
class X(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField()

class Y(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField()
    m = models.IntegerField()

xs = X.objects.filter(n__in=Y.objects.filter(m=m).values_list('n')).distinct()
```

**edit:** 
As noted in the comments this method will hit the db a lot

Comment: Just a note: doing it the second way that @kriegar has done there will cause O(n + 1) hits to the DB for each X object, super bad!! and would strongly advise against it. You should use the first method that he posted.

Comment: Well, the problem with the second way is that it's just very inefficient, as it possibly transports a very long list of values to the db... The first way, well I don't have a choice. Maybe I'll try to package it in a manager. However I think I start to develop a hatred for this framework. Argh!!!